# Duplication of characters in Warlords of Draenor

Tags: warcraft

As I understand the plot of *Warlords of Draenor* (the latest expansion for *World of Warcraft*)

> Garrosh Hellscream was sent back to Draenor shortly before the events of the first Warcraft game, and he prevented the orcs from drinking Mannoroth's blood and swearing fealty to the Burning Legion. Instead, a new timeline was formed where the orcs instead united to form the Iron Horde and Draenor never became Outland (as seen in *Warcraft II: Beyond the Dark Portal*). When the orcs came through the Dark Portal from their alternate version of Draenor, they came to the "prime" timeline of Azeroth where everyone remembers the original timeline's events.

This leads me to a question about individuals who should, in theory, exist in both places. For example:

> Prophet Velen - leader of the Draenai - resides in Exodar, which left Draenor and crashed on Azeroth. When the heroes of the Alliance go through the portal they meet an alternate version of Velen, who is still the leader of his people on Draenor.

On the other hand, we have a different example:

> Vindicator Maraad, a Draenai, who sacrifices himself to save Yrel and Durotan from Blackhand. A big deal is made about this sacrifice. However, this Maraad was from Azeroth; shouldn't there be a second Maraad on Draenor?

Why is the situation different for these two characters in what seems like identical circumstances?

Comment: Note that lore questions are allowed on gaming.stackexchange. Of course, they're also allowed here, and there's a lot of overlap in userbase betwixt the two sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes their is another version of him. The biggest mind twist in this, is that when garrosh goes back in time it creates an alternate reality, so in essence there is a draenor A that the horde is drinking manoths blood in and invading azeroth prime in our past x years ago, and a draenor B that garrosh has created the iron horde, and also invading azeroth prime, however in our current time.  So as long as he hasn't already died by the time we got to draenor B he should still be alive.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I haven't finished the legendary questline yet but I've pretty much done all the other zones & Alliance quests. I'm really hoping a future update brings in the Bronze Dragonflight (or what's left of them), perhaps even the Infinite Dragonflight. All of this is right up their alley, and both BC and WotLK left us with several plot-holes regarding those two.

Comment: you get to see chromie in the legendary questline, she's always nice to see.